# WM_PAINT not send when using WS_EX_COMPOSITE

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-messages

I'm working in a legacy application using MFC.

We have a mechanism to enable/disable controls depending on some business logic.

This mechanism is implemented in the CView-derived class. The way it works is all the views in the application derived from a common CView-derived class (CBaseView) and on the PreTranslateMessage all controls of the view are enabled/disabled.

This worked fine so far because all controls send at least WM_PAINT message when they need to be painted. So the system worked without the user having to move the mouse or anything. I recently added some drawing features and I had to use WS_EX_COMPOSITE to get ride of some flickering. With this flag activated my CView-derived class is not getting any called to PreTranslateMessage when creating the view....so the controls are not disabled until the user moves the mouse over the control.

I understand there is no way to send WM_PAINT using WS_EX_COMPOSITE but is there other message I can use to get the same behaviour???

**Edited:**

I am currently using the OnIdle approach but it has a big drawback, the windows doesn't become idle until after drawing all the controls...so when you enter the screen al controls are enabled and inmediately they are disabled...this makes a quite ugly effect!

More solutions???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Most UI enable/disable in MFC is done during idle processing - perhaps that's an option? You would need to override `CWinApp::OnIdle()` IIRC.

Comment: Thanks Roger! I google about that and found some interesting examples...I'll give them a try. I still would like to get other ideas though!

Comment: are you manually creating the controls in your `CView`-derived class, or is your view based on `CFormView`? Do you need to enable/disable controls depending on the values in your view's document and when they change?

Comment: No, I'm not creating the controls manually they are CFormView-derived classes. I need a mechanism that do not need to create code for any control in the views.

Comment: What is that "business logic" looking like that is implemented in PreTranslateMessage? Aren't there some events on which you can enable or disable the controls? PreTranslateMessage is not the optimal place to enable or disable controls.

Comment: No...the business logic is basically a structure with information about which controls should be disabled depending on the screen and/or logged user. I don't know if is the best place to enable/disable controls....but it's quite convenient, after creation all controls notify its parent that they are going to be draw so the code is isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical place to enable/disable controls would be [CView::OnUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1z3te7e.aspx), it is called by the framework after the view's document has been modified and from `OnInitialUpdate()`; you can also call this function if there is some change that would trigger re-evaluation of your business logic.

**EDIT**
After reading the question a bit more closely, what you could also do is to post a private message at the end of OnInitialUpdate and "catch" it in your PreTranslateMessage:

```
PostMessage(WM_APP, 0, 0);
```

Comment: That won't help if you have to disable controls based on external events (e.g. a Paste button that should only be enabled if the clipboard contains text).

Comment: You are right, but OP doesn't seem to have a dynamic logic (_the business logic is basically a structure with information about which controls should be disabled depending on the screen and/or logged user_) for enabling/disabling controls

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: sorry, forgot to add your user name to my previous comment

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I agree that OnUpdate and OnInitialUpdate is the place to enable/disable controls for a regular operations. But in this case this would require a lot of "plumbering". I need something that is called automatically and in background. Using the OnIdle state sounds good but I'm worried about performance. OnIdle will be called when the application is not processing messages but this do not mean is not working. We have a lot of working threads.

Comment: @EdwardClements Is a good option but you still need to send the application message everytime something changes the control status. With the WM_PAINT message I just need to invalidate the view. Moreover this is something I didn't comment in the question but the same mechanism is implemented in CBaseDialog for all the dialogs in the application and this approach will not work there. Anyway I implemented the OnIdle approach and it's working fine. I will accept your answer because I think your comments are useful and I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Calling InvalidateRect followed by UpdateWindow against the window in question will mark the entire client area as dirty and force an immediate repaint.  Remember that WM_PAINT is not really a message, in the queue in the usual sense, it is pushed out after all other messages have been processed for that window, which would include any invalidations of the area being drawn.  No message is generated at all if there are no invalid segments of the active window display.